# C++ Implementing class function with nested struct outside

Tags: c++

So, I want to make the code a bit more pretty in that I want the class def to contain just function declarations. Here is my code:

```
template <typename T>
class splay_tree
{
    struct node
    {
        T data;
        node* parent;
        node* left;
        node* right;
     };

     node* grandp(node* x)
     {
         return NULL;
     }

     node* error();
};

node* splay_tree<T>::error()
{
    return NULL;
}
```

My question then is how to move the `grandp` implementation below the `splay tree` definition. Note that its return type is `node*`, so gcc is giving me a hard time with this. Is it possible?

Comment: what hard time? Please show the broken code and the error you get.

Comment: Don't forget that the default access modifiers for struct/class are inverted, i.e. here your struct is a private inner class, as well as your grandp() function, but the fields of your struct are public.

Comment: @idclev463035818 this is a self-evident example. But as you requested, there is your broken code. I am not going to type the error for obvious reasons as this is about c++ not gcc.

Comment: @SilverFlash Typing the error is a very bad idea, but cutting and pasting it is very helpful. A little less attritude to those trying to help is appreciated as well.

Comment: Unrelated: Since C++11, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: @john Again, as more and more people seems to misunderstand this question. This is not about fixing an error. This is strictly a question about HOW to do it... And yes, sorry about my additude!

Comment: compiler extensions and typos in code are maybe irrelevant here, but they are a reality and including code and the error help to leave no doubt. Also questions that just ask "how to do it?" are much better received here when you show your attempt, because SO is not to replace books or reference manuals.

Comment: @SilverFlash I believe that the answer I gave is one way to do what you want (move the definition of `error` outside the class. Evg showed another way. If it's not working precise error messages will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this

```
template <class T>
typename splay_tree<T>::node* splay_tree<T>::error()
```

The return type of a method is not the the scope of method so `splay_tree<T>::` must be specified separately.

Plus since this is a template, you need `template <class T>`

Comment: I've tried this, it fails in gcc by saying the <T> has to be specified in the return type.

Comment: @SilverFlash Of course `typename`. Sorry about that, and thanks to Ted. Fairly useless answer.

Comment: I just verified. Thank you! And my apologies if I offended anyone.

Answer (score 6):

You've already gotten an answer but I'll put Evg's idea to use a trailing return type to bring `splay_tree<T>::node` into scope to show that alternative too:

```
template <typename T>
class splay_tree
{
    struct node
    {
        T data;
        node* parent;
        node* left;
        node* right;
     };

     node* grandp(node*);
     node* error();
};

template<typename T>
auto splay_tree<T>::grandp(node* x) -> node* // trailing return type
{
    return nullptr;
}

template <class T>
auto splay_tree<T>::error() -> node*         // trailing return type
{
    return nullptr;
}
```